# is there possible to write my own punycode converter in php without intl extension?

Tags: php, punycode

I do not have that much control of the remote server to install extensions, php is 5.3.8.
But I've noticed that there is possible to split utf-8 string with pcre.

So for example: `preg_split('@@u','bücher',-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

gives: `Array ( [0] => b, [1] => ├╝, [2] => c, [3] => h, [4] => e, [5] => r )`

or for chinese word: *中国/中华* it gives: `Array ( [0] => ńŞş, [1] => ňŤŻ, [2] => /, [3] => ńŞş, [4] => ňŹÄ )`

(the results are from non-unicode display), but it is clear that it is possible to split an `utf-8` string without international extensions and then (I think) it should be possible to get character codes and do calculations with them to create ascii url.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is?  Maybe posting what you are hoping to get out of the code from the sample input you provided.  Also, this is a helpful list of links regarding PHP and UTF-8: http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8

Comment: To which *international extensions* are you referring to? Can you add a list of those to your question? And yes, it's possible to get character codes out of binary data. If you want to get a UNICODE value for an UTF-8 character, the RFC describes how this is done: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629

Comment: What you want to do seems to work fine, doesn't it? What is the problem?

Comment: ok, I found it -> http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1509-PHP-Convert-from-and-to-IDNA-Punycode-domain-names.html- it is possible and has been done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only things you need to know is the bitmasks that signal double,triple,quad byte code points:

Table from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

```
Bits  Last Code Point  Octet 1  Octet 2  Octet 3  Octet 4

 7    U+007F           0xxxxxxx    -/-      -/-      -/-
11    U+07FF           110xxxxx 10xxxxxx    -/-      -/-
16    U+FFFF           1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx    -/-
21    U+10FFFF         11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
```

I don't speak php, but I'm quite sure existing code can be found that uses the shown bitmasks to scan a utf-8 char sequence without actually interpreting it

Comment: The easiest way in PHP would be to use mb_convert_encoding to convert to UTF-32 big endian and then `$codepoint = ord($c[1]) << 24 | ord($c[2]) << 16 | ord(c[3]) << 8 | ord($c[4])`.

Comment: And by the way, UTF-8 is limited to 21 bits nowadays.